# Cancel running Task on Dispose and race condition

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm building a wrapper around `NamedPipeServerStream` and `NamedPipeClientStream`. Currently my `Connect()` method on the `Client` looks like this:

```
    public async Task Connect(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, _connectCancellationTokenSource.Token);

        await _pipe.ConnectAsync(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_pipe.IsConnected)
            {
                _connectCancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
                _connectCancellationTokenSource = null;
                _pipe.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;
                Connection.Set();
                Connected?.BeginInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty, x => ((EventHandler)x.AsyncState).EndInvoke(x), Connected);

                BeginRead();
            }
        }
    }
```

and my `Dispose(bool)` like this:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _connectCancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

with the `base.Dispose(bool)` looking like this:

```
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposing) return;

        Connection.Reset();
        _pipe.Dispose();
        Connection.Dispose();

        _disposed = true;
    }
```

Basically I can't invoke `Dispose(bool)` while the connection Task is still running and waiting for it to finish is not an option as it might literally run forever.

My workaround was to create a linked `CancellationTokenSource` and use its token as the `CancellationToken` for the `Task`, allowing me to cancel it myself on `Dispose()`.

This however created a race condition where it was entirely possible that the client would connect and enter the `if (_pipe.IsConnected)` only to be disposed of immediately after, causing it to throw on `BeginRead()` (which also uses `_pipe`), hence the `lock` on both `Connect()` and `Dispose()`

However I'm not entirely sure that my approach is really all that sane, and looking for either some validation or ways I could improve this. I'm also concerned I might be putting a bit too much inside the `lock`...

Comment: A lock only helps if the resources are being accessed from multiple threads; it does nothing for asynchronous workflows that are all on one thread. What's your threading model here?

Comment: @EricLippert Well... crap. Didn't know that. While the main idea is for the library to be used by a single thread, I was trying to build it so that multiple threads could be used. Does that answer your threading model question? If not you'll need to be a bit more specific. :)

Comment: A [mcve] might help here.

Comment: @Enigmativity what would you like me to add? All the relevant code is already there with an explanation of what I'm trying to achieve and where the problem lies. I'll share more if needed, just let me know what you're after exactly.

Comment: Monitors are mutual exclusion for *threads*;  `void M() { lock(this.foo) { N(); } } void N() { lock (this.foo) { ... ` is perfectly sensible and does not block on the second monitor enter. A thread is perfectly able to re-enter the same monitor as many times as it likes.

Comment: Leaving the lock aside, I don't see what the problem is. You say you have a race where a client connects, a client disconnects, and code which is expecting the connection to be valid throws. That's awesome. If you don't catch the exception then the task returned by `Connect` will be in a faulted state, and if you do catch it, then it's caught.  This sounds like the system working to me; what's the problem?

Comment: @cogumel0 - A [mcve] means that I should be able to copy, paste, and run your code to see what the issue is. I can't do that with your code right now. So it's not minimally complete.

Comment: @EricLippert guess I was trying to ensure that it was safe for both `Dispose()` and `Connect()` to run without getting on each others toes. Initially my `Connect()` method did not return an awaitable `Task` but since it now does I suppose I'm just shifting responsibility to the consumer. They have the means to ensure that they only call `Dispose()` after `Connect()` has finished. If they choose not to do that then the code may throw, which is perfectly acceptable - so I can get rid of the lock. What about my usage of the `CancellationTokenSource` and cancelling the pending task on `Dispose()`?